# git format-patch cyrillic names

Tags: git, patch, cyrillic

When I create patches from my git repository, where I using Russian language for comments, the patches names looks like 0001-.patch, 0002-.patch and so on.

How can I force git to use commit oneline message for patches name or transliterate messages for file names?

Comment: What OS? What Git distribution and its version?

Comment: OTOH, I observe Git 2.1.4 on a GNU/Linux system with `ru_RU.utf-8` locale to behave like you describe. A small (but important, I reckon) addition is that the filename formatting routine seem to strip anything non-ASCII from commit short messages: if I end my short message with, say, "aaa", it will appear in the file name. You seem to end yours in a dot (contrary to best practices but it doesn't matter) and get that dot in the file names. Hence, I'd post a message to the main Git list (for developers). See [this](https://gist.github.com/tfnico/4441562) for pointers.

Comment: I use Gentoo and Debian 8. The Git version is 2.4.6

Comment: As I've said, this appears to be a problem in Git (that is, this is the behaviour implemented by design), so I have nothing to add to my suggestion in my previous comment.